# How to configure devtools to default to Chinese

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

The following has been configured

```
settings.PersistSessionCookies = true;
settings.Locale = "zh-CN";
settings.AcceptLanguageList = "zh-CN";
```

How can I configure the default developer tool to save in Chinese

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoHkB.png)

Comment: What do you mean by save in Chinese? Does Chrome support what you are attempting?

Comment: What version are you using? Exact version, not latest please.

Comment: latest version（100.0.4896.75）；devtools alway reset...i don't know how can keep save

Comment: It's likely CEF requires additional changes to support this, I'd suggest moving the discussion to https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php once it's fixed in CEF then the changes will flow through to CefSharp